# Google Sheets Apply formula based on cell value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We use Google Sheets to bid for work schedules.  Bidding is done in groups.  Sheet1 contains the employee PIN with their shift preferences (1-16) based on seniority.  Column U contains the IF/AND formula used to assign the employee to a shift based on availability and preference.  Column V contains the employees bidding group # based on the formula.

As it stands, I use the fill handle to drag the formula in Column U down by group, starting with group 1. When it is group 2’s turn to bid then I drag the formula down through group 2...so on and so forth.  What I would like is for the formula to automatically drag down (or appear) for the group when I select "Yes" on the 'Live Bid' sheet under the group #.  As I move from group to group, I need the previous groups formula to still show so the formula in column U is correct.

Hope this makes sense.

[Demo Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165-77OsejV-O5P5Cj72qQ_dQpiNnJ2T4_pdseEtrtec/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sometimes you are better off breaking your problems into multiple steps, such as helper columns so that your problem can be easily understood, modified, and solved. It is good you provided a demo link but you need to be more specific as to what formula you are having a problem converting into an array as right now you have multiple questions in this one question.

Comment: Sorry. I need help modifying the formula in Sheet1 column U. 
For group 1 (groups are shown in Column V), I want the formula in column U to include a condition that also considers what is in Live Bid A4. If A4=Yes then run the formula in column U. If A4=No then don’t run the formula. 
Group 2 would work the same way, but with Live Bid B4. Once group 2 is live I want the formula in column U to stay true for group 1. This would continue through all the groups.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the information in your comment to help those just reading your question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

paste in **U2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(((H5:H="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), H5:H,  
 IF(((H5:H="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), H5:H, 
 IF(((H5:H="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), H5:H, 
 IF(((I5:I="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   I5:I,  
 IF(((I5:I="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), I5:I, 
 IF(((I5:I="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), I5:I, 
 IF(((J5:J="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), J5:J, 
 IF(((J5:J="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), J5:J, 
 IF(((K5:K="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), K5:K, 
 IF(((K5:K="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), K5:K, 
 IF(((L5:L="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), L5:L, 
 IF(((L5:L="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), L5:L, 
 IF(((M5:M="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), M5:M, 
 IF(((M5:M="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), M5:M, 
 IF(((N5:N="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), N5:N, 
 IF(((N5:N="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), N5:N, 
 IF(((O5:O="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), O5:O, 
 IF(((O5:O="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), O5:O, 
 IF(((P5:P="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   P5:P,  
 IF(((P5:P="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), P5:P, 
 IF(((P5:P="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), P5:P, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((Q5:Q="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), Q5:Q, 
 IF(((R5:R="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), R5:R, 
 IF(((R5:R="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), R5:R, 
 IF(((S5:S="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), S5:S, 
 IF(((S5:S="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), S5:S, 
 IF(((T5:T="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), T5:T, 
 IF(((T5:T="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), T5:T, 
 IF(((U5:U="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), U5:U, 
 IF(((U5:U="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), U5:U, 
 IF(((V5:V="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), V5:V, 
 IF(((V5:V="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), V5:V, 
 IF(((W5:W="1N1 TWT(F)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N1 TWT(F)")<7)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="1N2 (F)SSM") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1N2 (F)SSM")<7)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="1S1 (S)MTW") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S1 (S)MTW")<7)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="1S2 TFS(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "1S2 TFS(S)")<7)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="2N1 FSS(M)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 FSS(M)")<5)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="2N1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N1 MIDS")<2)),   W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="2N2 (M)TWT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 (M)TWT")<4)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="2N2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2N2 MIDS")<2)),   W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="2S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 (S)SMT")<4)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="2S1 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S1 MIDS")<2)),   W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="2S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 WTF(S)")<4)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="2S2 MIDS")   * (COUNTIF(X3, "2S2 MIDS")<2)),   W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="3N1 (T)FSS") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N1 (T)FSS")<6)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="3N2 MTW(T)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3N2 MTW(T)")<6)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="3S1 (S)SMT") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S1 (S)SMT")<6)), W5:W, 
 IF(((W5:W="3S2 WTF(S)") * (COUNTIF(X3, "3S2 WTF(S)")<6)), W5:W,
 )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
 )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
 )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
 ))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

[image: 0]